# how to create ref in functional component in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I am trying to create ref in functional component .But getting different output as compare to to `class based component`.

here is simple `class based component` .In class based component I am getting correct refs

here is class based component
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vh86ou?file=src%2Ftabs.js

see ref mapping **(correct ref mapping)**
[image]

Same mapping I am trying to do with functional component **but getting different output why ?**

here is my function component
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nagea2?file=src%2FApp.js

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('---', tabRefs);
  }, []);
  const getTabProps = ({ title, key, selected, tabIndex }) => ({
    selected,
    children: title,
    key: tabPrefix + key,
    id: tabPrefix + key,
    ref: e => (tabRefs[tabPrefix + key] = e),
    originalKey: key
  });
```

I am getting this output
[image]

Why I am getting Ref from **HTMLLIELEMENT** instead of `TAB` component ?

**Update** :

I am trying to get `offsetWidth` still not able to get
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nagea2?file=src%2FApp.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('---', tabRefs);

    Object.keys(tabRefs).forEach(key => {
      console.log(key);
      if (tabRefs[key]) {
        const width = tabRefs[key].tab.offsetWidth;
        console.log(width);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't add the ref attribute to functional component** for reasons as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components).
You can use forwardRef function combined with useImperativeHandle hook to emulate class component ref, but you can't add ref to your Tab component as long as Tab is a function component.

For example, you can add some code to your Tab component like below.

```
const Tab = React.forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => {
  const liRef = useRef(null);
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    tab: liRef.current
  }));
  return <li ref={liRef}>{children}</li>;
});
export default Tab;
```

If you want to store all refs of all Tab component and call some functions of it later, you can add functions inside useImperativeHandle hook.

Comment: thanks for answering ..so is there any way to get the refs ? using functional component.can you modify some code

Comment: here is my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nagea2?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: I need mapping or need reference or all `tabs` `Tab {...getTabProps(tab)} />`

Comment: I want to store all `tabs` mapping and iterate it and get it's width

Comment: is there any alternate way to store refs ?

Comment: You can do it using useRef hook `const elementRef = useRef(null) ` and `<input ref={tabRef} />`

Comment: @AnuragKumar still not working..I am not able to get `offsetwidth`.see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nagea2?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: thanks @Topw but I am using your solution I am still not able to get offsetWidth.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nagea2?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: see update of my question I tried like this `useEffect(() => {
    console.log('---', tabRefs);

    Object.keys(tabRefs).forEach(key => {
      console.log(key);
      if (tabRefs[key]) {
        const width = tabRefs[key].tab.offsetWidth;
        console.log(width);
      }
    });
  }, []);`

Comment: Please try with the code I've just updated

Comment: @TopW3 thanks it working ..thanks a lot . Only one concern `ref` is used to access `tab ` property from `TAB component` is it correct statement ? 

second if you see in `class base component ` also have `context , props,renderTab , state ` property ...can we get  ?


or adding in more property `useImperativeHandle ` I will get ?

Comment: if I need more properties I will add like this `React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    tab: liRef.current,
props:props
  }));`

Comment: correct. so I wrote the word "emulate". You can add more properties or functions inside the useImperativeHandle hook return value

Comment: But I'm not sure why this is needed. I want to know the use case. It is recommended that don't overuse ref. We need to avoid ref as possible as we can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234487/discussion-between-user944513-and-topw3).

Comment: sorry for not replying. I was offline. please contact me anytime.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @TabW, function components do not have refs.  But **you don't need a ref to the `Tab` component itself**.  You can get the `offsetWidth` of the underlying `li` element just by forwarding the ref, without having to use `useImperativeHandle`.

Attach your forwarded ref directly on the `li`:

```
const Tab = React.forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => {
  return <li ref={ref}>{children}</li>;
});
```

And remove the `.tab` property from where you access it.

Comment: thanks can you check this question if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252201/how-to-reorder-item-or-move-selected-item-on-top-in-react-js